# Is it possible to transmit pointer to model from C++ to Qt Quick TableView?

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have class with QSqlDatabase and with pointer to QSqlTableModel in one class. I use pointer to QSqlTableModel, because initialization of database is going on in constructor and after that I create QSqlTableModel using this database (also in constructor but in heap already).
This class is registered type in qml and so I create it in QML. How is it better to point out TableView to the QSqlTableModel pointer of this class? If it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you're asking. I'm going to assume you want to share a pointer to your model with QML.

1. Have a `Q_PROPERTY` for it. All `Q_PROPERTY`s are automatically visible to QML.

   - When returning `QSqlTableModel*` you need to register that type, too. E.g.

     ```
     qmlRegisterUncreatableType<QSqlTableModel>(
         "NameOfModuleInQML", 1, 0, "QSqlTableModel",
         "Cannot instanciate QSqlTableModel from QML");
     ```
   - Note that you cannot do this then:

     ```
     property QSqlTableModel mytabmodel
     ```

     do this instead if you need to:

     ```
     property QtObject mytabmodel
     ```
2. Return it from a method of a class registered with QML (note that you must return `QObject*`). This is very likely what you want. E.g.

   ```
    class SomeClass : public QObject {
         // ...
    public:
        Q_INVOKABLE QObject *model() {
             return tableModel;
        }
        // ...
    };
   ```

   Then you can do this in QML:

   ```
   TableView {
       model: instanceOfYourclass.model()
       // other bindings

       TableViewColumn {
           title: qsTr("Name")
           role: "Name"
           width: 150
       }

       // and so on
   }
   ```
3. You can create a singleton

   ```
   QObject *tableModelProvider(QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine)
   {
       (void)engine;
       (void)scriptEngine;

       return new QSqlTableModel(...);
   }

   qmlRegisterSingletonType<QSqlTableModel>("NameOfModule", 1, 0, "NameInQML", tableModelProvider);
   ```

   This is a suitable approach if there is and ever will be only one instance of your model and if you don't need much to initialize it.
4. Set your model as a context property

   ```
    QQmlEngine engine;

    // ..
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("nameInQml", yourTableModelInstance);
   ```

Comment: If I use the first case you wrote (but without creating property QtObject in QML) I get the run-time error: "QMetaProperty::read: Unable to handle unregistered datatype 'QSqlTableModel' for property 'MyClass::tableModel'". If I use this with creating of property as you wrote I get "Unable to assign [undefined] to QObject*" error. The second method with Q_INVOKABLE works without errors but I cannot see data in TableView (I'll try to investigate it more deeply).

Comment: The model is declared in class as a "QSqlTableModel *m_tableModel". I am not sure, is it actually right to return pointer to model to QML instead of object?

Comment: When using option 1) and returning QSql... you *need* to register the type as pointed out above. Data being invisible is likely an issue of role names, check what's the output of `qDebug() << yourmodel->roleNames();` (include `<QDebug>` for this) is.

Comment: You likely need to set up the model before passing it the first time to a QML view, I guess.

Comment: Okay, it seems QSqlTableModel does not export role names (sadly). See http://qt-project.org/wiki/How_to_use_a_QSqlQueryModel_in_QML

Comment: That is: you need to subclass QSqlTableModel and re-implement roleNames, returning a mapping column <-> role name. Then you use those role names in the TableViewColumn to access the data.

Comment: Found example here (http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/41793), it works, but cells not editable and not updating when I insert something new. Anyway, the second proposed approach covers the question.

Comment: @dom0 very detailed answer thank you. For (2) I'd like to point out that the returned pointer must explicitly be `QObject*`. If it is `QSqlTableModel*`, the behavior gets weird: Sometimes it is properly recognized by the qml engine and sometimes not (resulting in the pointer being `undefined`).

Comment: @AyberkÖzgür in C++ , returning an object of base type (`QObject`) is not recommended for derived class objects (`QSqlTableModel`) .. isn't that UB ? while it works for pointer objects only .. it could eventually also be UB .. dont know!